How do I resolve AbiError: Parameter decoding error, or run out of gas error, when calling(get) from nodejs api route?
I'm using web3.js v4.7.0 to interact with my smart contract using nodejs/express. below is my code snippet for the Contract
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

contract Transactions {
    uint public count = 0;

    struct Transaction {
        uint id;
        string name;
        uint amount;
    }

    mapping(uint => Transaction) public transactions;

    constructor() {
        createTransaction("derived", 2000);
    }

    function createTransaction(string memory _name, uint _amount) public {
        count++;
        transactions[count] = Transaction(count, _name, _amount);
    }

    function getAllTransactions() public view returns (Transaction[] memory) {
        Transaction[] memory allTransactions = new Transaction[](count);
        for (uint256 index = 1; index <= count; index++) {
            Transaction storage transaction = transactions[index];
            allTransactions[index - 1] = transaction;
        }
        return allTransactions;
    }
}



I've initialized the Address and the ABI was copied from REMIX IDE, and I'm sure it works since the smart contract is behaving well there.
Now the issue comes when trying to make the get request, but the post request is working. Below is the code for the API route.js

function routes(app, db, accounts, transactionList) {
  app.get("/transactions", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const gasLimit = 20000000;
      const allTransactions = await transactionList.methods
        .getAllTransactions()
        .call({ gas: gasLimit });
      res.json({ allTransactions });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error getting all transactions:", error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Error getting all transactions" });
    }
  });
  app.post("/transactions", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { name, amount } = req.body;
      await transactionList.methods
        .createTransaction(name, amount)
        .send({ from: accounts[0] });
      const transaction = {
        name: name,
        amount: amount,
      };
      const result = await db.collection("transactions").insertOne(transaction);
      res.status(201).json({
        message: "Transaction created Successfully",
        contactId: result.insertedId,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Error creating transaction:", e);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
    }
  });
}

module.exports = routes;


Below is the error being generated after I attempt the post method.


Error getting all transactions: AbiError: Parameter decoding error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.
at decodeParametersWith (/home/steve/Projects/vcis_wallet_blockchain/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/commonjs/api/parameters_api.js:103:15)
at decodeParameters (/home/steve/Projects/vcis_wallet_blockchain/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/commonjs/api/parameters_api.js:213:75)
at decodeMethodReturn (/home/steve/Projects/vcis_wallet_blockchain/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/commonjs/encoding.js:125:56)
at ContractBuilder. (/home/steve/Projects/vcis_wallet_blockchain/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/commonjs/contract.js:672:61)
at Generator.next ()
at fulfilled (/home/steve/Projects/vcis_wallet_blockchain/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/commonjs/contract.js:21:58)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
innerError: undefined,
code: 205,
props: {
internalErr: AbiError: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.
at decodeParametersWith (/home/steve/Projects/vcis_wallet_blockchain/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/commonjs/api/parameters_api.js:94:19)
at decodeParameters (/home/steve/Projects/vcis_wallet_blockchain/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/commonjs/api/parameters_api.js:213:75)
at decodeMethodReturn (/home/steve/Projects/vcis_wallet_blockchain/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/commonjs/encoding.js:125:56)
at ContractBuilder. (/home/steve/Projects/vcis_wallet_blockchain/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/commonjs/contract.js:672:61)
at Generator.next ()
at fulfilled (/home/steve/Projects/vcis_wallet_blockchain/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/commonjs/contract.js:21:58)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
innerError: undefined,
code: 205,
props: {}
}
}
}


For some more context. this is the ABI

const TRANSACTION_ADDRESS = "0x0766512529e545515d908c2cf8962455c430D3d7";

const TRANSACTION_ABI = [
  {
    inputs: [
      {
        internalType: "string",
        name: "_name",
        type: "string",
      },
      {
        internalType: "uint256",
        name: "_amount",
        type: "uint256",
      },
    ],
    name: "createTransaction",
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: "nonpayable",
    type: "function",
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    stateMutability: "nonpayable",
    type: "constructor",
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "count",
    outputs: [
      {
        internalType: "uint256",
        name: "",
        type: "uint256",
      },
    ],
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function",
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "getAllTransactions",
    outputs: [
      {
        components: [
          {
            internalType: "uint256",
            name: "id",
            type: "uint256",
          },
          {
            internalType: "string",
            name: "name",
            type: "string",
          },
          {
            internalType: "uint256",
            name: "amount",
            type: "uint256",
          },
        ],
        internalType: "struct Transactions.Transaction[]",
        name: "",
        type: "tuple[]",
      },
    ],
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function",
  },
  {
    inputs: [
      {
        internalType: "uint256",
        name: "",
        type: "uint256",
      },
    ],
    name: "transactions",
    outputs: [
      {
        internalType: "uint256",
        name: "id",
        type: "uint256",
      },
      {
        internalType: "string",
        name: "name",
        type: "string",
      },
      {
        internalType: "uint256",
        name: "amount",
        type: "uint256",
      },
    ],
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function",
  },
];

module.exports = {
  TRANSACTION_ABI,
  TRANSACTION_ADDRESS,
};



And index.js

const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const { Web3 } = require("web3");
const routes = require("./router/routes");
const { TRANSACTION_ABI, TRANSACTION_ADDRESS } = require("./config");

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

// Define MongoDB connection URI
const uri = "";

// Define the async function to connect to MongoDB and perform operations
async function run() {
  let client;
  try {
    client = new MongoClient(uri);
    await client.connect();

    const db = client.db("Cluster0");

    const web3 = new Web3(
      new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545")
    );
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    const transactionList = new web3.eth.Contract(
      TRANSACTION_ABI,
      TRANSACTION_ADDRESS
    );

    routes(app, db, accounts, transactionList);
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3001, () => {
      console.log("Listening on port " + (process.env.PORT || 3001));
    });

    console.log("Connected to MongoDB and started server successfully!");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error connecting to MongoDB:", error);
  }
}

run().catch(console.error);


I tried to increase the GasLimit in the app.get route to a ridiculous number, but that didn't work.
I tried to alter the ABI and contract functions to change the return type, but I'm still getting the same error.

